# PHP: Adding commas between $_POST elements when putting array in file

Tags: php, arrays, post

The following is my code:

```
<?php
    #put the info the user just inputed into a file for later retrival
    file_put_contents("test.txt",$_POST, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

And this is the result I get in test.txt:

> JaneF16xyzWindows1215

How can I change the format of the result to be

> Jane,F,16,xyz,Windows,12,15

(have commas between the elements)

Answer (score 5):

Change it to

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', implode(',', $_POST), FILE_APPEND);
```

Note that this does not consider the possibility of array post values.